# What is the difference between DataMapper and ORM?

Tags: design-patterns, orm, datamapper

What is the difference between the DataMapper and ORM? I thought that the DataMapper is a form of ORM, is it not? If you would provide the defenition of a DataMapper and ORM in your own words I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you all for you help and support.

Answer (score 1):

From [P of EAA](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html): Data Mapper is a layer of [Mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/mapper.html) that moves data between objects and a database while keeping them independent of each other and the mapper itself.

ORM (Object Relational Mapping) is an possible implementation of Data Mapper. ORM is a technique/solution that provides an object-based view of data to applications which it can manipulate

Comment: Should also note that not all (or even most?) ORMs implement a Data Mapper pattern, e.g. Active Record pattern ORMs.